# Unable to use MySQL Connector/J with Servlets using TomCat

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to use MySQL in Java 8 (using Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0) with tomcat 8.0.9 on Windows 7 x64).

I put the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar` into my WEB-INF/lib directory.

When compiling the project as a normal Java application everything works. However, when I try to use the same code as a servlet, it throws

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

Moving the .jar file into TomCat's /lib directory didn't help either
(compiling as a normal application still worked though).

I haven't really changed anything, just upgraded from an older combination of Java, TomCat and Eclipse.

Apparently TomCat doesn't load the library/driver correctly; any ideas why that might be?

Comment: So how are you creating connections? Manually in your application using the DriverManager, or are you defining a datasource in Tomcat?

Comment: I tried both. Using DriverManager throws the mentioned exception. I was not able to define a datasource correctly yet, everything I got was "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'".

Comment: Strange indeed. I ask because that determines where you put the driver; if datasource it needs to be in tomcat/lib, if manually it needs to be in WEB-INF/lib (although tomcat/lib should always work). I think at this point you are better off to post the datasource definitions you have and the code you use to obtain a connection from it.

Comment: My xml files look like [this](https://gist.github.com/PotcFdk/3be03dac71ca845bf367), I'm then using `context.bind("jdbc/TestDB", datasource);` in my code.

Comment: bind()? You need lookup() of course

Comment: Changed back to lookup, now I get `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/TestDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].`

Comment: Then you are using the wrong path. The documentation explains what to do: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html . At this point one has to wonder how it could have ever worked before upgrading.

Comment: What do you mean by "path"? [These paths](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)? Nothing I do changes the NameNotFoundException.

Comment: ... how about the document I linked to myself? It has a clear example of how to define AND lookup a datasource through Java code. You are likely missing the java:/comp/env part of the JNDI path when doing the lookup.

Comment: I was looking at the MySQL section, while you were apparently referring to the oracle section. Thanks! Adding the java:/comp/env part fixed my issue. Do you want to post that as an aswer so I can upvote you?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you upgrade your version. You must download the latest version of both java and connector and then try this.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by "upgrading from an older version" - I replaced the old version with a new one.

Comment: This is happening due to version mismatch. Try to solve by re-installing the version compatible to both your server and your connector. I have faced such an issue and solved by changing my connector version.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling isn't the issue; this is a runtime problem.

The Tomcat docs are clear: the JDBC driver JAR belongs in the Tomcat server /lib, not the WEB-INF/lib for your application.

That exception usually means that the driver class was loaded, but the syntax of the connection URL string is incorrect.

Open the MySQL admin console and make sure you can access that database with the credentials you're providing to the app.

Comment: As I already said, moving the jar file into Tomcat's /lib directory didn't help. I am perfectly able to connect to said database with the used credentials.

Comment: As I already said, I don't think class loading is your issue.  I think your problem is an incorrect URL.  "Connect perfectly"?  Java appears to disagree with you.  You'll fix this faster if you stop insisting that you're correct with everything.  You're obviously not.

Comment: The issue has been fixed already, see the comments under the opening post.